# Domain of definition of a rational map is determined by several coherent sheaves of ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am reading the Hironaka's paper on desingularisation. One part of his work is about eliminating the indeterminacy of proper rational map. He says that this comes from the *Principalization of Ideal Sheaves* by the following fact

> Let $f$ be a proper rational map from a smooth algebraic variety $X$ to an algebraic variety $Y$, over a field characteristics $0$. Here "proper" means the projection from the graph to $X$ is proper. Then there is a finite system of coherent sheaves of ideals $J_1, \dots , J_r$ such that, if $h \colon X' \rightarrow X$ is a morphism from a smooth algebraic variety $X'$, then the domain of definition of $f\circ h$ is $\{x' \in X' \vert \exists i \;s.t. h^{-1}(J_i) \text{is invertible near} \;x'\}$.

The fact is clear when $Y$ is projective. But how to see the fact for general $Y$?